# ASP.NET MVC Submit form data into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ASP.NET mvc application with the view like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FormSubmit", "HomeController", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {    
            <fieldset>

                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend>Survey Form</legend>

                <br>
                <br>

                 <centre> <p> This is a survey for User X. <p>
                 </centre>

                    <!-- Multiple Radios -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="q1">Any Plans to attend college?</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label for="q1-0">
                                    <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="q1-0" value="1">
                                    Yes
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label for="q1-1">
                                    <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="q1-1" value="2">
                                    No
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

      <input type="submit" name="SaveButton" value="Save" align="center">  

       </fieldset>

 }
```

I created the controller in HomeController:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult FormSubmit(int Q1)
    {
        return Content(Request.Form["SaveButton"]);
       //  return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Now when I try the button it gives me a:

```
  Server Error in '/surveyapps' Application.
  The resource cannot be found.
```

I did exactly as said in this post at stack-overflow: [asp.net mvc form not posting parameter values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328402/asp-net-mvc-form-not-posting-parameter-values)

Any way the error could be resolved? I sam sure if I get the form values then I can just insert them into database.

Comment: Why are you using "SaveButton" ? (in Content(Request.Form["SaveButton"]);) - You are trying to read a value from a submit btn - makes no sense.

Comment: no, its just to see that I get some value from the form post operation... it makes no sense otherwise.

Comment: You Can try And remove this Line:new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }

Comment: Just Change "HomeController" to "Home" in your beginform it works...

Comment: Ohh, havent seen that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, change the HomeController to Home

like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FormSubmit", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

The framework handles this with "Controller" suffix automatically